# SPARK persist example

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

can any one please help how to set/reset the persist storage level to different one from default.
I tried the below and I may be incorrect. Please help me correcting it.

code below :

```
scala> val lines = sc.textFile("/data/retail_db/products/part-00000").persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
<console>:27: error: not found: value StorageLevel
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to import `StorageLevel` before using it, like that

```
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
```

Comment: Yes it works. I forgot to import the library. Thanks

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.